# Is it possible to use a React Component for one field of a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jsx, form-for, react-rails

I have a working Rails form in which I'm trying to implement one field as a React Component (as an input with autosuggester). I have the React autosuggester working perfectly (so I don't want to use a library for it), and now I'm trying to figure out how to get the selection back in the `form_for` data. The form currently looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for (@user, url: :interests_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_interests do |builder| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= react_component(...(@interests already passed in successfully) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The react component has an input field in it, and I'd like to get the value of that back into the form somehow. Is there a way to grab it from its parent container? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd still love to know the answer to this, but ultimately I just converted the entire form into a React Form with ajax --> no Rails involved.

Comment: i have the same question. is it possible?